# Nested Promise Function Using Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I have the following function, which accepts an argument (an array of "names") and then checks data from my firebase database for each user against that array.

It uses that to compile an array of "settings" for each user with their email, and the names that the user shared with the list fed in as an argument. The function looks like this.

```
fbDaemon = ({ folderNames }) => {
  const settings = [];
  ref.once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach(user => {
        auth.getUser(user.key)
          .then(function(userRecord) {
            let email = userRecord.toJSON().email;
            let zips = [];

            user.forEach(setting => {
              let dep = setting.val().department;
              if(folderNames.includes(dep)){
                zips.push(dep);
              }
            });

            settings.push({ email, zips });
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
          });
      });
  });
});
```

Essentially, it's going through my entire database and compiling a list of the settings that I will pass onto the next function. The end result should look something like this:

```
[ { email: 'example@example1.com',
    zips: [ 'Drug Enforcement Administration', 'Executive Branch' ] }, 
 { email: 'example@example2.com',
    zips: [ 'FEMA', 'Congress' ] },
];
```

The problem that I'm having right now is I'm not able to return the "settings" array at the appropriate time.

**How can I reconfigure this function so that the settings array is only returned when the entire function has run?**

In other words, I'd like to return a resolved promise with the settings array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `Promise.all()` here, to resolve an array of promises (where each item in the array corresponds to a call to `getUser` for that item/user) ?

So, something along these lines:

```
fbDaemon = ({ folderNames, folderPaths }) => {
  const settings = [];

  return ref.once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {

      // Collect all users from snapshot into an array
      const users = []
      snapshot.forEach(user => { users.push(user) })

      // Create promise for each user, and use Promise.all to 
      // resolve when each "user promise" is complete
      return Promise.all(users.map(user => {

        // Be sure to add "return" here
        return auth.getUser(user.key)
        .then(function(userRecord) {
          let email = userRecord.toJSON().email;
          let zips = [];

          user.forEach(setting => {
            let dep = setting.val().department;
            if(folderNames.includes(dep)){
              zips.push(dep);
            }
          });

          settings.push({ email, zips });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
        })
      }));
  }).then(function() {

     return settings;
  });
};
```

Comment: Two notes: you should return the original promise: `return ref.once(...)` and also should return the settings array in the `.then` of the `Promise.all`: `return Promise.all(...).then(() => { return settings; })`.

Comment: @CRice thanks for the suggestions - have just revised answer to capture those :)

Comment: Thank you. Would never have thought of that. One quick question––why do we need to include all of these return statements? What exactly are they accomplishing here?

Comment: @HarryCramer you're welcome - yes it's a bit to think about. An async/await based approach is possible here and it would make the code a bit clearer (opted for Promise based approach to better match the question) - do you need help with that?

Comment: rather than `settings.push({ email, zips });`, I would `return { email, zips };` - and then, you wouldn't need `const settings=[]` or `.then(function() { return settings; })` at all

Comment: @DacreDenny If you know how to reconfigure it into async/await and it's cleaner, then I'd love to see it. If not that's cool, it's already working it's just a little convoluted.

Comment: @HarryCramer no problems - does this help? https://gist.github.com/dacredenny/c2a202aba7cfaf375f2c5fe82899f6c5